# Receive messages from GCM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

How can i simply receive messages on my web page from GCM.
I have tried the same with Google channel, it's working but in background it always pools to server.

Can any one explain me with code example.

Thanks

Comment: You can check my answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942190/phonegap-cordova-app-notifications/39964929#39964929 Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add some details? This question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad and vague question, but if you want to learn about push notifications, check out this [Google code lab](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/).